# Dismissing a sheet not working since update to swift 5

Tags: swift, macos

I have some code that was working under Swift 4.x. Since I have updated the application to be Swift 5 it has stopped working.

I have read the documentation for Swift 5 and double checked my code.

Funnily enough I had a similar problem when I updated the code from an earlier version of 4 to a later version of 4, but that turned out to be they had changed how things should work. In this case that does not seem to be the case.

I have a top level class

```
import Cocoa

class QuizManagementController: NSViewController {
  ...
  var currentSheet: NSViewController!
  ...
}
```

An extension is responsible for showing a custom view controller as a sheet.

```
extension QuizManagementController {

  ...
  func showQuestionSheet(questionType: Int16, isUpdate: Bool) {
    ...
    currentSheet = controller
    presentAsSheet(controller!)
  }
  ...

}
```

And another extension that acts as the SheetDelegate

```
extension QuizManagementController: QuestionSheetDelegate {

    func questionCancelled() {
        self.dismiss(currentSheet)
    }
    ...
}
```

When an action is trigger by clicking a button on the sheet (in this case the cancel button), I expect the sheet to dismiss.

I have placed a break point on the `self.dimiss` line above and I know this is being called, but the sheet does not disappear.

I have also checked that the all of `currentSheet` does contain a reference to the controller that I expect it too.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `self.dismissViewController(currentSheet)` or `currentSheet.dismiss(self)`?

Comment: I don’t think so, unless i’m reading this wrong : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsviewcontroller/1434489-presentassheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Objective-C method `dismissViewController:` is now in Swift `dismiss(_:)`

```
func dismiss(_ viewController: NSViewController)
```

The Objective-C method `dismissController:` is in Swift `dismiss(_:)`

```
@IBAction func dismiss(_ sender: Any?)
```

`self.dismiss(currentSheet)` calls `dismissController:`. Solution: cast `currentSheet` to `NSViewController`.

```
self.dismiss(currentSheet as NSViewController)
```